# Save and Show Google Maps image

Tags: php, google-maps

I have a website (guidemanche.com) that loads static maps images directly from Googlemaps. It works fine if you are connected to Internet. But if I am disconnected, or in case of a site copy on CD, no more image. 
So, I would like to DL the image created, store it on the server and display it back in my page as a jpg file.
But it doesn't work and I have a black image.

My code is:

```php
<?php
$url="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=[(#LATITUDE|scannav)],[(#LONGITUDE|scannav)]&zoom=14&size=450x400&maptype=hybrid&format=jpg&markers=color:blue|label:W|[(#LATITUDE|scannav)],[(#LONGITUDE|scannav)]&sensor=false";

$filename="googleimg/#ID_ARTICLE.jpg";

if (!$handle = fopen($url, 'r')) {
echo "Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier ($filename)";
exit;
}

$contents = stream_get_contents($handle);
fclose($handle);

$handle2=fopen($filename, 'w');
// Ecrivons quelque chose dans notre fichier.
if (fwrite($handle2, $contents) == FALSE) {
echo "Impossible d'écrire dans le fichier ($filename)";
exit;
}

fclose($handle2);
?>
```

where #ID_ARTICLE is a Spip (CMS) function.

How can I parameter the GoogleMaps code to have the good image and get it back?
Thks